# Visual Studio 2013 Installation block

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, visual-studio-2013, block

I have VS 2012 Update 4 installed on my machine (Win7 SP1 x64) and i want to install VS 2013 along side it.The installation blocks and here's the log message:

> MUX:  Stop Block: OlderFLPOnFLPBlocker : The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install vs by doing some changes in registry .[This](http://johndelizo.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/visual-studio-2013-setup-blocked-the-product-version-that-you-are-trying-to-set-up-is-earlier-than-the-version-already-installed-on-this-computer-fixed/) article will help you.

http://johndelizo.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/visual-studio-2013-setup-blocked-the-product-version-that-you-are-trying-to-set-up-is-earlier-than-the-version-already-installed-on-this-computer-fixed/